# Android Project with a specific gradle configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

On Android Studio, I would like when i create  each new project, this project must be able to load my specifi configuration and not the default conf of gradle.  I quote here the gradle-Wrapper configuration. I have tested init.gradle and it do the job but it  can not change the configuration on the build.gradle